# How to open an IOS project with no ".xcodeproject" file?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently received an application developed by a third party which was packaged in a ".jpa" archive. I changed the file extension to ".zip" and was able to extract the contents.

There are a lot of iOS app type files in the extracted folder (plists, nibs, including "MainController.nib", a bunch of .png files - and one "mom" file.

I'm used to seeing an "xcodeproj" file somewhere, but it's been a few years since I developed an iPhone app.  I don't really see any code or delegates or header files etc.

I'm currently running Xcode 6.11. How do I open this app?

Comment: The .ipa file that you received is the compiled binary. It will include supporting resources like the ones you listed, but you will not be able to see the source code. It is *not* the Xcode project, it is a generated archive that is packaged and ready to ship to iTunes (or elsewhere).

Comment: The above should be the answer really.